# How to list distinct values of pyspark dataframe wrt null values in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

i have a pyspark dataframe:

```
rowNum      Vehicle      Production
     1      1234         5678
      2      null        1254
      3      null        4567
      4      null        4567
```

i want to pick all the distinct values of Production in a list format where Vehicle is null. How to achieve this?

```
result:
production list=['1254','4567']
```

how to achieve this in pyspark dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
# Using Spark 3.3.0

# Dataset as per the question
data = [
     [1,   '1234', 5678]
,    [2,   'Null', 1254]
,    [3,   'Null', 4567]
,    [4,   'Null', 4567]    
]

cols = ['rowNum', 'Vehicle', 'Production']

# Creating Dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)


# list comprehension to represent the distinct Production values on 'Null' Vehicles
list = [p.Production for p in df.select('Production').distinct().where("Vehicle == 'Null'").collect()]

list
```

The output I am having is the following:

[image]

Comment: just wnated to know like how to achieve the same if Vehicle has None type instead of "null"

Comment: On top add:

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

Then modify the list comprehension with this:

list = [p.Production for p in df.select('Production').distinct().where(F.col("Vehicle").isNull()).collect()]